# Windows authentication + Katan gives Infinity redirect loop

Tags: c#, .net, owin, windows-authentication, katana

Works without any problem if I use "Forms" as the authentication mode. But if I change to "Windows", I'll get an infinity redirect loop to my loginpage "http://localhost:41855/LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FLoginPage.aspx%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FLoginPage.aspx%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252F..."

Found out that if I remove the "LoginPath" it works well even with Windows authentication. But is that a valid way to solve this problem? Or is the any other options?

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application.AuthType",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/LoginPage.aspx"),
            //CookieName = ".AspNet.Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application",
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
        },
        PipelineStage.Authenticate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication is intended to be used on every request, not with cookies, so you should remove UseCookieAuthentication entirely.